# How can I add a GIF with a label to a QListWidgetItem?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I'm trying to display an animated GIF on the left side of a QListWidgetItem in a QListWidget with the label text following. I've been reading that QLabels hold QMovies which can run GIF animations and that I'd need to create a custom widget and use that instead of the default QListWidgetItem, but I've had no luck. Does anyone how to do this? Am I over-complicating things?

I've written up a basic test case below:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class List_Widget_Gif(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, label_text, gif, parent=None):
        super(List_Widget_Gif, self).__init__(parent)
        # Layout
        horizontal_box_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        # Create text label
        self.text_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.text_label.setText(label_text)
        # Create label to apply GIF to (Apparently this is the best thing to use for GIF in this case?)
        self.icon_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(gif, QtCore.QByteArray(), self)
        self.icon_label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        # Add widgets to layout
        horizontal_box_layout.addWidget(self.text_label)
        horizontal_box_layout.addWidget(self.icon_label)
        #Set the layout
        self.setLayout(horizontal_box_layout)


class TestUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestUI, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setObjectName("TestUI")
        #Vars to pass
        self.my_gif = "my_cool_animation.gif"
        self.my_text = "This is awesome text"

    def setup_UI(self):
        #Create Default List Widget
        list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        # Create Default List Widget Item
        default_list_item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        # Create Custom List Widget with label and GIF motion
        custom_list_widget_item = List_Widget_Gif(self.my_text, self.my_gif)
        # Add default item to list widget
        list_widget.insertItem(list_widget.count(), default_list_item)
        # Set the default item to the custom one with the gif motion.
        self.ui.layerList.setItemWidget(default_list_item, custom_list_widget_item)
        #Set into UI
        self.setCentralWidget(list_widget)

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = TestUI()
    test.setup_UI()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: @DennisJensen Would you be able to elaborate a bit more? I've only ever had to use super() for classes that are UIs. PyCharm even bugs me to add super to my classes that are not UIs if they have a def__init__() but I've had no reason to add them.

Comment: 1) You MUST use it consistently, and document that you use it, as it is part of the external interface to your class, like it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>First you have a typo (it should throw an exception) so you have to change `self.ui.layerList` to `list_widget`.</sub>

Correcting the above there are several possible causes of error:

- The margins must be removed from the layout of the custom widget:

  ```py
  horizontal_box_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
  ```
- Do not use relative paths since they are the cause of silent errors, it is better to build the absolute path based on the location of another element. If I assume that the .gif is in the same folder as the .py then you can use that information to do so it changes:

  ```py
  import os

  CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  ```

  ```py
  self.my_gif = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "my_cool_animation.gif")
  ```

Comment: Thanks again! The margins was the issue, I definitely prefer setting them in the custom widget as opposed to resizing default items (non-destructive).

Answer (score 1):

It works, you just need to resize the default item to the size of your custom item.

```
def setup_UI(self):
    #Create Default List Widget
    list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    # Create Default List Widget Item
    default_list_item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    # Create Custom List Widget with label and GIF motion
    custom_list_widget_item = List_Widget_Gif(self.my_text, self.my_gif)
    # Add default item to list widget
    list_widget.insertItem(list_widget.count(), default_list_item)
    # Set the default item to the custom one with the gif motion.
    list_widget.setItemWidget(default_list_item, custom_list_widget_item)
    default_list_item.setSizeHint(custom_list_widget_item.size())
    #Set into UI
    self.setCentralWidget(list_widget)

    self.show()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The margins were indeed the issue and I set them to 0 in the custom widget. Working well now!